# shinydashboard : getting specific default page while using uiOutput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I was making reactive shiny web page and stucked at the code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "header"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar")),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("test")
  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  output$sideBar <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName ="dashboard", icon = icon('dashboard')),
                menuItem("DBcentor", tabName ="dbcenter", icon = icon('database'))
    )
  }) 
  output$test <- renderUI ({
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", uiOutput("dashboardbody")),
      tabItem(tabName = "dbcenter", uiOutput("dbcenterbody"))
    )
  })
  output$dashboardbody <- renderUI ({
    box("Dashboard Body")
  })
  output$dbcenterbody <- renderUI ({
    box("Dbcenter Body")
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I used `uiOutput` to build body but after shiny app is loaded, nothing comes out at the dashboard page.

I changed my code like this,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "header"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar")),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", uiOutput("dashboardbody")),
      tabItem(tabName = "dbcenter", uiOutput("dbcenterbody"))
    )
  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  output$sideBar <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName ="dashboard", icon = icon('dashboard')),
                menuItem("DBcentor", tabName ="dbcenter", icon = icon('database'))
    )
  }) 
  output$dashboardbody <- renderUI ({
    box("Dashboard Body")
  })
  output$dbcenterbody <- renderUI ({
    box("Dbcenter Body")
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Of course it works and `box("dashboadbody")` comes out at the first page.

I want to use `uiOutput` because i should use `input data` to build menus and items.
Any ways to use `uiOutput` and get `box("dashboard")` on the default page at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "header"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar")),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("test")
  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  output$sideBar <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName ="dashboard", icon = icon('dashboard')),
                menuItem("DBcentor", tabName ="dbcenter", icon = icon('database'))
    )
  }) 
  
  output$dashboardbody <- renderUI ({
    box("Dashboard Body")
  })
  output$dbcenterbody <- renderUI ({
    box("Dbcenter Body")
  })
  updateTabItems(session,"menu","dbcenter")
  updateTabItems(session,"menu","dashboard")
  
  output$test <- renderUI ({
    tagList(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", uiOutput("dashboardbody")),
        tabItem(tabName = "dbcenter", uiOutput("dbcenterbody"))
      ))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Oh, you tabbed dbcenter and returned to dashboard using updateTabItems! Thanks a lot it works. Do you know the reason it doesn't work at the first time when i use uiOutput?

Comment: Not sure.  As you are processing in the server with `renderUI`, it is not making dashboard as active tab.